# Convert text date to date in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, regex, date, if-statement, google-sheets

I am trying to convert date from a column that is a text type, when i try to format directly by Google sheets format option, it only formats a few dates but others not, I have tried using DATEVALUE function but i get the following error:
DATEVALUE parameter '26/05/2022' cannot be parsed to date/time.

I have no idea how to proceed with this date cleaning and correctly formatting, any help will very much appreciated.

[Sheet example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VAqaJ2oSYJdVtqTchQalfIS1fU5Qo9foT6RZkO3oTxc/edit#gid=2012873403)

Comment: what is your locale? share a spreadsheet with the date in text.

Comment: I have, there is a link where says "Sheet example" with the data as text

Comment: we can't decide if in row#16 the date is the 1st of May or the 5th of January! Where and How are they coming rom?

Comment: I spent a good few minutes trying to figure this out myself. When you rich click the cell to change the format (as you would do in excel) there is nothing in the context dialog to change the 'type', only validation. But there is a dropdown you can click that is on the main menu that can change the type from say 'text' to 'date' or 'number' or whatever. Just look around for it and you will find it there. I had the opposite problem where I wanted to run macros/js expressions on a string of a date, not on the date to improve performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want datevalues try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IFERROR(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, 
 "(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d{2,4})", "$2/$1/$3")*1, A2:A)*1, A2:A))
```

[image]

Comment: This is the solution i was looking for, thank you very much!